# Load jQuery Mobile dialog without head?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

In my jQuery Mobile site, I have a button in my header like this:

```
<a href="/foo.html" data-rel="dialog" data-icon="grid">Foo</a>
```

The problem is that JQM expects me to redefine the head with all the scripts and CSS. This is so awkward especially for a dialog (not to mention slow). I would like my dialog just to have the content of my grid without having to redefine a full blown html page. Is this possible?

Comment: You don't have to include anything more than `<div data-role="dialog">...</div>` in your document. That's all jQuery Mobile will add to the DOM anyway. However it's a good idea to have a full `<head>` section in each document for SEO. It's also a good idea to have a full `<head>` section in-case the user refreshes the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the dialog in the same page ( multi-page layout )

- http://jsfiddle.net/cJyYb/

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="thePage">
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#theDialog" data-rel="dialog">Open dialog</a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Add the dialog here -->
<div data-role="dialog" id="theDialog">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
        <h1>Dialog</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
        <h1>Delete page?</h1>
        <p>This is a regular page, styled as a dialog. To create a dialog, just link to a normal page and include a transition and <code>data-rel="dialog"</code> attribute.</p>
        <a href="#thePage" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="b">Sounds good</a>       
        <a href="#thePage" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html

Comment: This could create problems down the road. If this page is navigated to via AJAX then the `data-role="dialog"` element will be excluded as jQuery Mobile only grabs the first `data-role="page"` or `data-role="dialog"` element in a document, ignoring the rest of the document.

Comment: Thanks Phill and Jasper for he heads up. I was able to change the data-role from "dialog" to "page" and it worked as expected. I think this is the correct way of doing it: http://jsfiddle.net/cJyYb/1/